# amp-iframe scrolling on iOS 11

Tags: ios, amp-html

I have a problem that an iframe content on my AMP page is not scrollable on an apple iphone with iOS 11. Is there any fix - I only found entries about the "-webkit-overflow-scrolling" - but that is already included in the current amp-iframe component?

Does anyone know a solution for this - here is my page:
https://www.zugspitz-arena.com/unterkuenfte/ferienwohnungen.html?amp=1

Thanks for any hints ...

Comment: When you choose tags for your questions, please read the description that is displayed below the tag editor or by hovering on the tag name. I'm pretty sure you meant the [tag:amp-html] AMP and not the [tag:amp] AMP. If you don't use proper tags, your question won't be seen by the people who could answer it.

Comment: we have a similar problem. Note that on your example page there are two vertical scroll bars. This may be caused by the iframe and your sidebar menu. If you look at the iframe target (the html) the problem does not appear to occur.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the entire `<amp-iframe>` tag inside a `<div>` tag like this:

```
<div class ="scroll-wrapper">
    <amp-iframe> ....</amp-iframe>
</div>
```

Then in the css:

```
.scroll-wrapper{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
```

and give the height and width accordingly to the iframe.

Comment: @RodrigoReis yes, it works, but it's important that you add width/height to your wrapper div.